# How to determine where a require request originated?

Tags: php, require

Is there any way to determine from within a required script, where that require call was made from?

So if Script B is required by Script A. How can I determine from within Script B that it is Script A who is making the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`debug_backtrace`](http://php.net/debug_backtrace) might help you.

Comment: Ah, I should have thought of this. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

a $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] in scripr B,  will show the current file (script A)